# how can set Android Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri number from lstBook = new ArrayList<>();

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, phone-call

I have created android app like gallery which have some images using `gridview` fragment.

Functionality is working fine also my click button for dail `USSD` code working.

1st of all sorry because I don't know how can I explain my requirement or question.

I need help that how can I get `USSD` code from `gridview` like `Title`, `Description`.

Here is my code :

```
lstBook = new ArrayList<>();
lstBook.add(new Book("*111", "Categorie Book", "Description book", R.drawable.person7));
```

Here is my code of next activity :

```
    public class Book_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView tvtitle,tvdescription,tvcategory;
        private ImageView img;
        private Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_book_);


            tvtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);
            tvdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
            tvcategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCat);
            img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bookthumbnail);

            // Recieve data
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String Title = intent.getExtras().getString("Title");
            String Description = intent.getExtras().getString("Description");
            int image = intent.getExtras().getInt("Thumbnail") ;

            // Setting values

            tvtitle.setText(Title);
            tvdescription.setText(Description);
            img.setImageResource(image);

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                    String phone = "*1111111111";
                String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone+encodedHash));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want `String phone = tvtitle` from my gridview

My intent showing as `*1111111111#`  but I want `*111#`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solve my question by myself and am answering here for other user can get help

Change String phone String phone = "*1111111111"; 
with 
String phone = tvtitle.getText().toString();

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                //String phone = "*1111111111";
            String phone = tvtitle.getText().toString();
            String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone+encodedHash));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
```